# SSRS 2008 Execution Service LoadReport Error

Tags: ssrs-2008

I'm using SSRS 2008 (NOT R2)

I have a report deployed to a dev server, I'm trying to render the report as a pdf by calling the execution service.

The error I am getting is 
This operation is not supported on a report server that runs in native mode. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.OperationNotSupportedNativeModeException: This operation is not supported on a report server that runs in native mode.

Two things I notice: one is that web service wsdl shows LoadReport having two parameters - report path and history id, but when I generate a service reference for the ReportExecution2005.asmx, the LoadReport method has 5 parameters: trusteduserheader, reportPath, historyid, serviceinfoheader, and executionheader

I have tried adding the service reference with and without ?wsdl at the end of the url but the result is the same

Here's the code I'm using:

```
ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient rs = new ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient("ReportExecutionServiceSoap", "http://xxx:80/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx");            
        rs.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("aaa", "aaa", "aaa"); 

        rs.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;



 // Render arguments

    byte[] result = null;
    string reportPath = "/Invoices/InvoiceStandard";
    string format = "PDF";
    string historyID = null;
    string devInfo = "";

    // Prepare report parameter.

    ParameterValue[] parameters = new ParameterValue[3];

    parameters[0] = new ParameterValue();
    parameters[0].Name = "PartyID";
    parameters[0].Value = "19758";
    parameters[1] = new ParameterValue();
    parameters[1].Name = "Contract";
    parameters[1].Value = "17703"; // June
    parameters[2] = new ParameterValue();
    parameters[2].Name = "FinancialPeriod";
    parameters[2].Value = "MAR-2012";
    string encoding="";
    string mimeType="";
    string extension="";
    Warning[] warnings = null;
    string[] streamIDs = null;

    ExecutionInfo execInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
    TrustedUserHeader trusteduserHeader = new TrustedUserHeader();
    ExecutionHeader execHeader = new ExecutionHeader();
    ServerInfoHeader serviceInfo = new ServerInfoHeader();


    execHeader = rs.LoadReport(trusteduserHeader, reportPath, historyID, out serviceInfo, out execInfo);

    rs.SetExecutionParameters(execHeader, trusteduserHeader, parameters, "en-us", out execInfo);

    try
    {                
        rs.Render(execHeader,
                    trusteduserHeader,
                    format, 
                    devInfo, 
                    out result,
                    out extension, 
                    out encoding, 
                    out mimeType, 
                    out warnings, 
                    out streamIDs);
    }
```

Here's my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ReportExecutionServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://xxx:80/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ReportExecutionServiceSoap"
        contract="SSRS.ReportExecutionServiceSoap" name="ReportExecutionServiceSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this report loaded from some front end or is it loaded from DLL? To me it looks like you are using ASP.net Application. In this case you could use reportViewer object to pull the report for you all the heavy lifting can be done by the ReportViewer and you can then just save the file as PDF
using something like this

```
 reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(Config.ReportServerURL);
 reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = String.Format("{0}/{1}", Config.ReportServerEnvironment, reportName);
 reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportsCredentials(Config.ReportServerUser, Config.ReportServerPassword, Config.ReportServerDomain);

reportViewer.GetDocumentStream(SSRSFormatType.Pdf, documentName);
```

Here reportViewer is the reference to ReportViewer object on the screen.

Comment: Actually that's what I wound up doing - Thanks Bhupendra!

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem with SSRS 2008 R2, but I did not want to resort to calling the report viewer control.

Above, Rick Hodder was using the following statement:

```
TrustedUserHeader trusteduserHeader = new TrustedUserHeader();
```

This statement will cause the `OperationNotSupportedNativeModeException` error he encountered if the SSRS installation is not configured with a certificate for SSL connections.  Check the SSRS Logs for an error entry that contains:

> ERROR: TrustedHeader Not Supported in Native Mode.

If this is the case, you need to either [configure the server to work with SSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345223(v=sql.105).aspx), or use null for the trusted header.

```
TrustedUserHeader trusteduserHeader = null;
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  I was banging my head against the wall trying to get this working.  Sure enough http on the Server and trustedheader was breaking it with this same exception.

Comment: Thank you so much, I wasted 3 days trying to figure out that red herring error message. This saved me.